# Подключение к бд

Tags: php, sql, база-данных

Добрый день.

Помогите разобраться, а точнее, наведите на правильную мысль.

У меня все содержимое перенаправляется с одного домена на все поддомены, добавлена запись А в общем.

*.domen.ru --- sub.domen.ru

Таким образом, у меня получается, поддомены берут содержимое домена. У поддоменов разные базы, и нужно как-то сделать, чтоб подключалось к нужной бд. Естественно, я делал это через `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, брал имя поддомена, и explode отделял его, сверяя имя поддомена и имя бд. Если оно идентично, то делал подключение.

Все работает, но одно НО. Я хочу в дальнейшем сделать, чтобы можно было менять поддомен на домен. Тут все упирается в то, что имя и адреса уже другие будут, и как подключаться к бд в таком случае??? Думал, сделать наподобие отдельных файлов config для разных поддоменов, куда будет вписываться имя бд, и по этому конфигу подключаться к нужной, даже если бд и адрес не идентичны друг другу. Но ведь у меня все содержимое с *.domen.ru --- sub.domen.ru, и естественно, все, что я положу внутрь sub.domen.ru, не будет работать, а будет работать, лишь если это у меня в domen.ru.

Помогите!

Comment: Прочитал около 4 раз, и так и не понял ничего.

Comment: у вас единая файловая для всех сайтов? Или у каждого своя папка и свой код?

Comment: нет. код один на все поддомены. у каждого поддомена своя папка но код общий из домена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, думаю, тут все просто, если я правильно понял.

Создаете файл `db.conf.php`, в котором пишете:

```
    <?php
         $database = array(
             'sub.domen.ru'=>array('user'=>'логин', 'password'=>'пароль', 'dsn'=>'если надо в общем все параметры для коннекта',...),
             'subtwo.domen.ru'=>array('user'=>'логин', 'password'=>'пароль', 'dsn'=>'если надо в общем все параметры для коннекта',...),
....
);
    ?>
```

И вот таким вот образом все свои домены прописываете.
Потом в самом верху подключаете данный файл, и при конкретном случае обращаетесь к
`$database[ $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ]`, желательно, конечно, проверить, есть ли такой еще.